# Fibonacci sequence inconsistency

Tags: fibonacci

I've made a short program to generate the fibonacci sequence in a length specified by the user. At the moment when I run the code and input a digit like 6, it will display the sequence as follows:

1 , 1,2,3,5,8,

How do i get rid of the initial spaces while the string stays on one line? below is my code

```
#user intiger input
print("\n")
f = int(input("Enter length of sequence: "))
print("\n")


f1 = 1
f2 = 1
multiply = 2


if f <=0:
   print("Enter a positive integer for the length: ")


elif f == 1:
   print("The Fibonacci sequence: ")
   print("\n")
   print(f1,end=',')

else:
   print("The Fibonacci sequence: ")
   print(f1,",",f2,end=",")
   while multiply < f:
       f3 = f1 + f2
       print(f3,end=",")

       f1 = f2 
       f2 = f3 
       multiply += 1

print("\n")
```

Comment: I would change the title, as it has nothing to do with the fibonacci sequence, but with the output. Also, add some tags so people will actually find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
else:
print("The Fibonacci sequence: ")
print(f1,end=",")
print(f2,end=",")
```

This is the simplest solution as per my perspective..
but by seeing your code its seems like output should be rid of initial spce
however try as per suggetion & let me know output